# How to calculate the "average engagement time" of GA4 using Big Query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to create a "session level" table using big query. For this, I use the session_id, user_speudo_id and other metrics/dimensions.
When I try to calculate the "average engagement time" of GA4, I use the following formula.

However, I get 19 minutes with BigQuery while GA4 shows an average engagement time of 30 minutes.
Has anyone ever calculated this metric with BigQuery?

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT ( SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'ga_session_id') AS session_id,
    max((select value.int_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'engagement_time_msec')) as timeOnSite_ms 
FROM tableXXXX
```

Comment: I think the question here is how GA4 computes the average engagement time that shows up in their UI. Once you have sorted this out, apply the same logic when computing it through BigQuery

Comment: can you share the sql you tried and the output you got? it will also help if you can share sample data & the output expected on that data.

Answer (score -1):

try this one

```
SELECT 

distinct (SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'ga_session_id')  AS session_id,
sum((select value.int_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'engagement_time_msec'))/1000 as timeOnSite_sec


FROM table_xxx

group by session_id
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I don't see an `AVG` in this answer.